# How do I link to a local/internal file in Drupal 7?

Tags: files, navigation

Is there a way to get and display a local file's path in Drupal 7?

We have very large files on intranet, so I would like to instead display the file locations.

The ideal scenario would be to browse & select a file. Then instead of uploading the file drupal would save the file path i.e. x://projects/shared/example.mov

Comment: may be NFS can help?

Comment: Please tell us how you tried to do it and why it does not work. As far as I know nothing stops you from putting `file:` schema in content or in link field. It would be a waste of time (both ours and yours) to describe with details ways you already found not suitable in your situation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution for Intranet deployments only.

Install the Any Menu Path and the Filter Allowed Protocols modules.

Enable both modules and add "file" to the configuration  > text format > allowed protocols.

Edit the link in your menu to read file:///directory/file.html. Check the box labeled "No Path Validation" and save.

If it still doesn't work, check to make sure your browser doesn't need extensions or privacy settings adjusted to accept the file:/// protocol.